# Как во VUEX передать значение из input в создаваемый на странице элемент?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, framework7

Не могу понять как передать значение из **input** в **store**. Когда я нажимаю на кнопку **«Добавить элемент»**, мне нужно создавать блок с кнопкой удаления этого блока и текстом введенным в **input**, а затем массив из созданных блоков с текстом из input должен сохранятся в **localstorage**. Сейчас у меня создаётся и сохраняется только блок без текста, никак не могу разобраться как передавать в создаваемый блок введённый в *input* текст.

**Код компонента**

```
  <f7-block-title>Some items</f7-block-title>
  <f7-block v-for="(cat, n) in getCats" :key="n">
    <span>{{ cat }}</span> //сюда должен добавляться текст из input
    <f7-button fill color="red" @click="removeCat(n)">Delete Cat</f7-button>
  </f7-block>
  <f7-list form>
    <f7-list-input :value="tempCat" type="text"></f7-list-input>
    <f7-button fill color="blue" @click="addCat(tempCat)">Add some item</f7-button>
  </f7-list>

import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      tempCat: '',
    };
  },
  computed:{
    ...mapGetters([
      'getCats',
    ]),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions([
      'addCat',
      'removeCat',
    ])
  }
}
```

**Код во VUEX**

```
Vue.use(Vuex);


function loadLocalStorage() {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cats'));
  } catch(e) {
    localStorage.removeItem('cats');
    return [];
  }
}

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      name: '',
      password:'',
      cats: loadLocalStorage(),
    },
    getters:{
      getCats: state => state.cats,
    },
    actions: {
      addCat(context, data) {
        context.commit('ADD_CAT', data);
        context.commit('SAVE_CATS');
      },
      removeCat(context, data) {
        context.commit('REMOVE_CAT', data);
        context.commit('SAVE_CATS');
      },
    },

    mutations: {
    ADD_CAT(state, data) {
        state.cats.push(data);
        console.log(state.cats);
    },
    SAVE_CATS(state) {
      localStorage.setItem('cats', JSON.stringify(state.cats));
      console.log(state.cats);
    },
    REMOVE_CAT(state, index) {
      state.cats.splice(index, 1);
    },
},
});
```

**Ссылка на GitHub**
https://github.com/MrRJDio/ex1

**Gif как должно работать и как работает сейчас**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос, что у вас в localStorage сохраняется.

Comment: `localStorage` не реактивен по умолчанию и требует специальной прослойки.

Comment: А вот эта часть `cats: loadLocalStorage()` вызывается только один раз при инициализации, а не каждый раз при обращении к `cats`.

Comment: В state вообще должно быть все по нолям, null и пустые массивы. А все действия с localStorage переносятся в `actions`.

Comment: Я вот этот пример ( https://codepen.io/cfjedimaster/pen/qoYbyW ) с официального сайта VUE ( https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/client-side-storage.html#Working-with-Complex-Values ) пытался переделать что бы он работал во VUEX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> v-model is not supported on f7-list-input / f7-input vue components. Instead, just use the combination of value property and @input event

Должно быть, согласно [документации](https://framework7.io/vue/inputs.html#input-v-model):

```
<f7-list-input :value="tempCat" @input="tempCat = $event.target.value" type="text"></f7-list-input>
```

Тоже решил накрапать [тык](https://codepen.io/russsiq/pen/VNoaBg).

Comment: Переделал под framework7. Спасибо огромное!  Видимо я как-то неправильно учу vue, как-то он мне тяжело даётся.

Comment: Это  framework7 вам такой геморой подкинул. Кто знает сколько раз вы об него споткнётесь.